Converting English Text and Latex Equations to PDF
I often write small documents involving mathematical equations with English explanations. I write the mathematical equations in LaTeX (I do this all in notepad, i.e. the free version that comes pre-installed on most computers).
I am looking for some online website/free program where I can CTRL C + CTRL V all the contents from my notepad file, the website renders the text and equations together, and the output is a PDF file.
Does anyone know if this is possible? Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks!

Welcome. // Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/overleaf/info

perfect - i think this is what I was looking for! thank you!

Are you familiar with http://latex2png.com/?

Notepad? I  do not use Windows since the Pleistocene, maybe now is different ...  but for sure there are many better free editors  to type LaTeX. Even if you will compile the files online, without installing LateX, if you will type  off-line It is worth taking a look at some  editors. Note that some could be overkill for and most human beings, but others are not more complicated to use than a pacifier.
